# What's the difference between .NET Core and PCLs?

Tags: c#, .net, cross-platform, portable-class-library, .net-core

I was writing up the supported platforms for my PCL recently, one of which is other PCLs. I was confused if my library (which targets .NET Framework 4.5 and Windows/Phone 8.1) can be used in .NET Core projects as well.

As I understand it, PCLs allow you to share code across multiple platforms without recompilation, while .NET Core does that as well. The only difference is that .NET Core targets a *few* more platforms, i.e. OS X and Linux, and is open source.

So essentially, I don't see how .NET Core is any different than Microsoft rebranding the PCL and saying "**PAY ATTENTION** we're going open source and targeting non-Windows platforms!"

So the bottom line is, are PCLs compatible with .NET Core, and vice versa? What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a beautiful article series about it which solved my questions around it ...

https://oren.codes/2015/06/16/demystifying-pcls-net-core-dnx-and-uwp-redux/
https://oren.codes/2015/07/29/targeting-net-core/

.Net Core has all his libraries (e.g. System.IO) in separate NuGet packages (each of them available for the SDKs DNX, UWP and .Net 4.6). Third party libraries target `dnxcore50` (DNX) or `uap10.0` (UWP) if they access the platform natively or rely on their features. If they do not access the platform but only rely on other packages, they should target `dotnet`.

`dotnet` effectively means: I am compatible with any platform which satisfy my dependencies (your library XYZ "dotnet" which uses System.Reflection `dnxcore5+net45` could not be used by a UWP `uap10.0` app). This effectively ends the combinatoric nightmare of the platforms. The previous target combination `dnxcore5+net45` created an intersection between the platforms libraries and each addition would make the situation even worse. `dotnet` on the other side does not restrict the library on a target but instead forwards this restriction decision to its dependencies (where suddenly new restrictions like the famous `unicorn` platform can show up).

Therefore as a library author you can target `dotnet` if you just need other libraries.

Answering your question:

- Your PCL is compatible with .Net Core style environments like DNX and UWP if you add the target `dotnet`, `dnxcore50` or `uap10.0` depending on the need of your library (see Owen's article for same basic compatibility with the contract Profile 259).
- .Net Core is much more than a set of PCLed libraries. It is a new CLR, a new organized framework (packaged in small parts) and the infrastructure for new .Net SDKs (DNX, UWP, and whatever comes next). The term ".Net Core" targets both, the base class library "CoreFx" and the CLR "CoreCLR". But the real platforms are in reality DNX (by ASP.Net team) and UWP (by Windows team).

All of that answer is my current understanding of the .Net Core library situation. It is work in progress, and like mentioned in the posts, not yet public documented.

*NOTE DEC 2016: Be aware, `dotnet` as the predecessor to `netstandard1.x` has changed in its concept starting with `netstandard2.x` (.NET Core 2.0; ~JUN 2017). Beginning with `netstandard2.0` there will be **one** common contract (the netstandard.dll) which all platforms (.NET Core, .NET Framework, Xamarin, Mono, Unity3D) implement. This contract will be extended over time and the platform have to either drop support for the latest standard, throw NotImplementedException or implement it.*

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is they both are in concept different.

- .NET Portable built upon the .NET Full, .NET Core, Windows Phone,etc, as sort of 'bridging layer'.
- It actually has no concrete implementation, consider it a 'Package' of assemblies of the 'Interfaces'(contracts).
- The scope of .NET Portable 'Package' is dynamic, depends on what 'Targets' platforms you are going to 'bridge'. It's a intersection of the platforms you target, the more platforms the smaller package.
- During runtime, this Portable layer is hooked/adapted to the real implementation of .NET full, .net core or...